# Creating a sticky hover effect with jquery

Tags: jquery, css, show-hide, sticky

I'm trying to create an effect which is just a little more complex than css (and apparently I) can manage.

The idea is to have one of the 5 DIVs active on page load and then until a different DIV is hovered, the the previous stays active. Essentially there will always be an active element.

All that needs to be done is to hide .promoExpand and show on hover.

Here is what I have so far:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.promo').mouseenter(function () {
        $(this).find('.item').addClass('promoExpand').siblings().removeClass('promoExpand');
    });
});
```

and a chunk of the HTML.

```
 <div class="promo">
    <img src="img/thumb/gratings.jpg">
    <h3>Fibreglass</h3>
    <div class="item">
      <p>These products are for the home. We specialise all of our decking for use by you.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Thanks for any help all,

Tom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[siblings](http://api.jquery.com/siblings) will look for elements with the same parent and it looks like your `.promoExpand` elements will be in different areas.  Use this instead:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.promo').mouseenter(function () {
        $(".promoExpand").removeClass('promoExpand'); //Remove all promoExpand classes here
        $(this).find('.item').addClass('promoExpand'); //Add the new one here.
    });
});
```

Comment: There's just one quirk, hope you can help. The <p> is visible on the non active <DIV>'s, rather than hidden. Any ideas? Many thanks.

Comment: CSS: `.promo .item { display:none }` `.promo .item.promoExpand { display:block` That way your .item div will be hidden by default, but shown when the promoExpand class gets added.

Comment: I was missing the second part to that piece of magic. Perfect.

Answer (score 0):

The call to `siblings()` wont work (I assume you have lots of `.promo` elements). Do something like this:

```
$('.promo').bind('mouseover', function () {
    $('.item').removeClass('promoExpand');
    $(this).find('.item').addClass('promoExpand');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try taking a look at this:

javascript: (i removed all promoexpand classes first, then add it to the one being hovered)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.promo').mouseenter(function () {
    $('.promoExpand').removeClass('promoExpand');
  $(this).find('.item').addClass('promoExpand')
});

});
```

working example: (don't mind my CSS, i put some dummy css on the elements to clarify visually)

http://jsfiddle.net/QHa7M/1/

Answer (score 0):

This is another option, set your active item to start with, then onhover iterate through all of the promo boxes and switch classes.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.promo').mouseenter(function() {
        $('.promo').each(function() {
             $(this).removeClass('active');
        });
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
 });
```

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/QHa7M/21/

I think thats what you want!